# Pandas decimal number to date conversion

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a timestamp column that contains some data in the formats shown below.
Could you please help explain to me how I can convert it into a consistent timestamp or date format?

> ```
> 2020-04-24 11:00:00
> 2020-03-18 09:00:00
> 2020-07-06 08:00:00
> 43851.333333333336
> 43878
> 43848.458333333336
> ```

Any help or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: So... it looks like an Excel artifact. Can you fix the data upstream?

Comment: second D Lathrop: this kind of thing is usually easier to fix while reading/parsing than fixing after a botched parse

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @DanielLathrop and @anon01 -- it's ideal to fix the data upstream.  If that's not possible, here is a function that handles both ISO dates and Excel dates.  (I'm assuming Excel 1900 format, not Excel 1904 format.)

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
import pandas as pd

def convert(t):
    ''' Convert date (ISO format) or Excel 1900 format to pandas Timestamp.'''
    if isinstance(t, (float, int)):
        return pd.Timestamp('1899-12-30') + DateOffset(days=t)
    elif isinstance(t, str):
        return pd.to_datetime(t, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='raise')
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'{t} not recognized')

# reference:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/1900-and-1904-date-system

# test Excel date, using Microsoft published example
d = 35_981
actual = convert(d)
expected = pd.Timestamp('1998-07-05')
assert actual == expected

# sample data
timestamps = [
    '2020-04-24 11:00:00',
    '2020-03-18 09:00:00',
    '2020-07-06 08:00:00',
    43851.333333333336,    # these are Excel timestamps
    43878,
    43848.458333333336,
]

# sample conversions
[convert(t) for t in timestamps]

# converted dates
[Timestamp('2020-04-24 11:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-03-18 09:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-07-06 08:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-01-21 08:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-02-17 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-01-18 11:00:00')]
```

More details on Excel dates here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/1900-and-1904-date-system

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp examples are unclear,

Timestamp conversion to DateTime Conversion in Python can be done in the following way:

```py
from datetime import datetime
result = datetime.fromtimestamp(43878)
print(result)
```